# Saving and Restoring View Changes

Tags: 3d-view

**Edit/Note**: I edited the title of this question to match the only answer that seems to be available for this situation. Original question was how to "Undo/Redo View-port Changes"

**Original Question:**

I'm pretty sure Blender does not have any direct way to undo view-port changes (similar to Max - if I rotate the view, I can press a command to go back to the starting point of that rotation). But has anyone figured out any trick or found any script that accomplishes the same thing?

I'm surprised so few people have asked about this. I definitely abused this ability in my Max days, and wouldn't mind doing it in Blender, if its possible!

Edit: Another similar question would be the possibility of saving view-port orientations and reloading them via commands. Is something like this possible without a lot of hassle?

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: maybe the trick is to use several cameras, you can switch from one to another as you want (select and ctrl 0) and you can align the selected camera to the view (ctrl alt 0). Also, to make sure that they won't move, lock their location or create some location keyframes.

Comment: Yes, that sounds like a reasonable solution! Thanks!

Comment: I'd rather have the Shift-Z feature (or similar) to simply undo the view change. Looks like this has been brought up a few times before:
https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/QLdbbc/
https://developer.blender.org/T47391

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an addon called Stored Views (3D View: Stored Views) which comes with Blender 2.80. This simple extension allows you to save views (location & rotation of viewport). The UI for it is located in the [N] sidebar panel under View -> Stored Views.

You can save and name any (?) number of views and quickly restore them by pressing their respective buttons. No cameras required. Although it actually allows you to save the current view as a camera as well.

It is not exactly what I originally asked for (restoring viewport changes), but it is the next best thing. Maybe actually better in terms of workflow.

Hopefully this will help those (like me) who model objects at crazy orientations.